# Is there a way to style just for Adobe Digital Editions?

Tags: javascript, css, adobe, epub

When building an `.epub` file I have found that ADE (Adobe Digital Editions) doesn't support a lot of standard CSS properties and I was curious to know if there is a JavaScript framework or CSS hack to target specific issues with ADE, (example: `margin: 0 auto`).  So my question, is there a way to target ADE's CSS with a CSS hack or JavaScript for common issues?

Comment: I think we can rule out JavaScript frameworks, since ADE does not do JavaScript. It’s a good practical question otherwise, though I’m afraid other e-book readers have similar faults and there is very little we can expect them to handle reliably (basically, the features we used on web pages in mid-1990s...).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which reader using ADE are you worried about? Thankfully, this technology looks like it's going to die sooner rather than lter.